# Restrict the use of SSL to only one directory in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, wordpress, rewrite

I have a SSL certificate installed and running well with Apache 2.2.14. Now, I want to restrict the use of https to just one directory, namely www.example.com/shop. If a user goes to https://www.example.com or any other URL but www.example.com/shop, I want to force http instead of https.

I'm running Wordpress on this site and can't for the life of me figure out how to write the correct rewrite rules for this (I bet simple) scenario. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't think of any good reason to actively block the use of HTTPS, but this should do it...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple rewrite rule would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You could also use is the [SSLRequireSSL directive](http://www.apache-ssl.org/docs.html#SSLRequireSSL) in the .htaccess file for that directory to completely bar access to that folder over HTTP even if the rewrite rule gets ignored for some reason.

**P.S.** I think you can use `%{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}` in place of `%{HTTPS}` above.

Comment: I recommend to use the static server name (e.g. www.example.com) instead of %{HTTP_HOST} in above rewrite rule. Mostly SSL certificates are bound to specific host names and so you can take care of using the correct host name.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use the [SSLRequireSSL](http://www.apache-ssl.org/docs.html#SSLRequireSSL) in the shop directory .htaccess and [SSLDenySSL](http://www.apache-ssl.org/docs.html#SSLDenySSL) elsewhere?